# calling a function from opencl kernel with the concept of pass by value

Tags: kernel, opencl, pass-by-value

what if i want to use pass by values concept. for example:

```
void sum(int &u, int &v)
{    return u+v;  }

__kernel void testing(__global int *a, __global int *b, __global int *c)
{    int i = get_global_id(0);
     int u = max(a,b);
     int v = min(b,c);
     int x = sum(u,v);
}
```

now my error is at '&' symbol. i am unable to pass arguments using pass by reference concept. what to do?

Answer (score 8):

C does not support passing a variable by reference, Opencl(v1.x) kernel works as C99. You need to  use direct pointers(which is a pass-by-value).

```
int sum(int *u, int *v)
{    return (*u)+(*v);  }
```

OpenCL v2.x can compile C++ but still it is needed to be supported by drivers and hardware first.

Comment: I wonder how can you return a value from a void return type function.